# React Bootstrap fails to render

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've just installed React Bootstrap and started to learn using it

I started by doing tutorials on http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/react-0.13.3/build/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-0.13.3/build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo_bootstrap_react.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I copied total tutorial of React Bootstrap Button, like this:

```
const buttonsInstance = (
  <ButtonToolbar>
    {/* Standard button */}
    <Button>Default</Button>

    {/* Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons */}
    <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>

    {/* Indicates a successful or positive action */}
    <Button bsStyle="success">Success</Button>

    {/* Contextual button for informational alert messages */}
    <Button bsStyle="info">Info</Button>

    {/* Indicates caution should be taken with this action */}
    <Button bsStyle="warning">Warning</Button>

    {/* Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action */}
    <Button bsStyle="danger">Danger</Button>

    {/* Deemphasize a button by making it look like a link while maintaining button behavior */}
    <Button bsStyle="link">Link</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
);

ReactDOM.render(buttonsInstance, mountNode);
```

I don't know what the hell is going on. Nothing is rendered. Did I do anything wrong? I downdloaded React Bootstrap and already included it in HTML file. This is impossible!

Comment: Can you check the error of Chrome developer tool, or, maybe, Firebug?

Comment: I tried `console.log(buttonInstance)` and got 2 errrors:

`Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.

Uncaught ReferenceError: ButtonToolbar is not defined`

It's no way the tutorial in documentation is wrong

Comment: Which version are you using? The most recent version requires React 0.14.

Comment: 0.13.3.
But even when I try to include React 0.14, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are loading the distribution bundle without CommonJS or AMD you'll need to access the global ReactBootstrap for all the components.

So change your example code to:

```
const buttonsInstance = (
  <ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
    {/* Standard button */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button>Default</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Indicates a successful or positive action */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success">Success</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Contextual button for informational alert messages */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="info">Info</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Indicates caution should be taken with this action */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="warning">Warning</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="danger">Danger</ReactBootstrap.Button>

    {/* Deemphasize a button by making it look like a link while maintaining button behavior */}
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="link">Link</ReactBootstrap.Button>
  </ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
);

ReactDOM.render(buttonsInstance, mountNode);
```

Comment: I think you can `var ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar` and make your code a bit more readable. Also `var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button`.
 You will have something like `<Button bsStyle="warning">Warning</Button>`
`